# Leveling the field for a race competition

Tags: experiment-design, scales, games

I'm not sure if this is really a statistics question, but I can't think of a more fitting Stack Exchange for it.

My friends and I at work are having a competition to see who can decrease their one-mile time over a three month span the most. We originally decided to use percentages to see who decreased their time the most; however, we realized an issue with this: it takes more effort to decrease low initial times by a little than high initial times with relatively high decreases.

Say Billy and Alice ran initial miles and got times of 10 minutes and 4 minutes, respectively. At the end of the three months they ran and got times of 7 minutes (Billy) and 3 minutes 45 seconds (Alice). If we used percentages, Billy would have won. But we know that wouldn't really be fair. Alice decreasing her time from 4 minutes to 3:45 would be an an incredible feat; Billy decreasing his time from 10 minutes to 7 would be good, but would require less effort than Alice put in.

How do we reward a runner like Alice, or penalize a runner like Billy in order to make the competition fair?

Comment: Cool question, +1! I can see this being something like how we look at error rates instead of success rates. 80% success to 90% sounds bigger than 95% to 99%, but taking a 20% error rate down to 10% is only halfing the error rate, while taking a 5% error rate down to 1% results in an 80% reduction in error rate. Maybe play a similar game with the slowest time as your bound instead of 100%.